# Como enviar notificação Push

Tags: android, push-notification

Atualmente faço uma verificação quando o usuário abre o *app*.
Primeiro ele verifica se está conectado. Se não estiver, não faz o comparativo.
Se estiver conectado, ele compara a versão atual com a versão que está no Play Store.

Assim, mando um `Toast` dizendo que o *app* está atualizado ou tem uma atualização na loja.

Como, ao invés desse `toast`, enviar uma notificação *push*?

**Obs.:** todos os tutoriais que vi só mostram como enviar via servidor, etc.

Comment: Acho que o que você quer não é uma notificação push, e sim uma simples [notificação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), do tipo que aparece quando se abre a barra de notificações do android. Notificação push na verdade não passa de uma informação que o servidor envia para o seu programa, é o seu programa que pode então exibir ou não uma notificação do android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isto usa se o [NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)

Segue um exemplo:

```
/**
 * Identificador da Notifição
 */
public static int ID_NOTIFICACAO = 9817;

private void gerarNotificacao(){
    /**
     * Vamos criar  um PendingIntent para abrir a url
     */
    String url = "https://play.google.com/store";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    final PendingIntent openUrl  =  PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


    /**
     * Vamos criar uma acão para a Notificação
     */
    NotificationCompat.Action openAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(
            android.R.drawable.btn_default, // Imagem do botão
            "Abrir o Google play", // Texto do botão
            openUrl);

    /**
     * Vamos criar um NotificationCompat.Builder
     */
    // Criamos o builder da notificão
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // titulo da Notificsação
            .setContentTitle("Atenção")
            // Imagem que será exibida na notificação
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            //  Icone que será na barra de notificação do smartphone
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert_notification)
            .setContentText("Existe uma atualização disponível no Google Play!")
            .addAction(openAction);

    /**
     * Pegamos o NotificationManager
     */
    NotificationManager manager = NotificationManager.class.cast(getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));

    /**
     * Exibimos a notificação
     */
    manager.notify(ID_NOTIFICACAO,builder.build());


}
```

Para remover a notificação:

```
NotificationManager.class.cast(getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancel(ID_NOTIFICACAO);
```

Comment: Perfeito. Exatamente isso.